# Masonry, infinitescroll and curvycorners

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, curvycorners

I use Masonry and infinitescroll and it works great together. I have tried to add curvycorners.js and make it load every time infinitescroll loads a new page, but to be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Does anyone know how I can add the code below, so that it loads everytime infinitescroll loads a new page.

```
curvyCorners.addEvent(window, 'load', initCorners);function initCorners() {
  var settings = {
    tl: { radius: 5 },
    tr: { radius: 5 },
    bl: { radius: 5 },
    br: { radius: 5 },
    antiAlias: true
  }
  curvyCorners(settings, ".post");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a class using the usual round corners CSS that works in all browsers - even in IE9 see http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers For something that simple, a plug-in seems overblown?

Comment: So, you gave what John Raasch mentions a go? Benefit is you just assign a class to existing and appended .masonry-brick elements, so there's no fiddling with nasty plugins. Unless you must design for Opera and IE7, but who wants to do that?